# XCTAssertThrowsError failing when expression throws

Tags: swift, xcode8, xctest

I have the following test code:

```
var returnValue: String?

XCTAssertThrowsError(returnValue = try CommandExecutor.ExecuteXCRun(launchPath: "", arguments: [])) { (error) -> Void in
    XCTAssertTrue(error is CommandExecutionError)
}
```

Where `CommandExecutor.ExecuteXCRun` is defined as:

```
public static func ExecuteXCRun(launchPath: String, arguments: [String]) throws -> String?
```

The method does throw an error during tests as expected, however the test is failing and strangely even notes that the method is throwing an error:

> error: -[SwiftXcodeToolsTests.CommandExecutorTests
>   testEmptyArgumentsThrows] : XCTAssertThrowsError failed: throwing
>   launch path not accessible -  Test Case
>   '-[SwiftXcodeToolsTests.CommandExecutorTests
>   testEmptyArgumentsThrows]' failed (0.203 seconds).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I pasted the code into a new project, and it worked. That is, the test passed when the function threw, and failed when it didn't. So that code isn't the problem.